# Powershell Menu

Tags: powershell, menu, ping, restart

I am looking to have this menu that I have been frankensteining and learning powershell while doing so, I am a systems admin I and trying to learn PS and more  networking to grow in career. Any edits and advice is much appreciated I just bought a ps book and youtubing a lot!

```
Function Menu  {
Clear-Host        
    Do
    {
    Clear-Host                                                                       
    Write-Host -Object 'Please choose an option'
    Write-Host     -Object '**********************'
    Write-Host -Object 'Scripts to run' -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host     -Object '**********************'
    Write-Host -Object '1.  Ping PC '
    Write-Host -Object ''
    Write-Host -Object '2.  Restart ELP Desktops '
    Write-Host -Object ''
    Write-Host -Object '3.  Restart NOVI Desktops '
    Write-Host -Object ''
    Write-Host -Object '4.  Check PC Storage '
    Write-Host -Object ''
    Write-Host -Object 'Q.  Quit'
    Write-Host -Object $errout
    $Menu = Read-Host -Prompt '(0-4 or Q to Quit)'
 
    switch ($Menu) 
    {
        1 {
            $Computer = Read-Host Please Enter Host name
            Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computername $Computer | `
            Where-Object {$_.IPEnabled -match "True"} | `
            Select-Object -property DNSHostName,ServiceName,@{N="DNSServerSearchOrder";
            E={"$($_.DNSServerSearchOrder)"}},
            @{N='IPAddress';E={$_.IPAddress}},
            @{N='DefaultIPGateway';E={$_.DefaultIPGateway}} | FT 

            pause
            }
        2 
            {
                restart-computer -ComputerName ######## -force
            }
        3 
            {
                restart-computer -ComputerName ######## -force
            }
        4
            {
                # Ask for computer name
                $Computer = Read-Host "Please Enter Host name"
                Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer -Filter DriveType=3 | Select- 
                Object DeviceID, FreeSpace, Size |pause
            }
        Q 
            {
                Exit
            }   
        default
            {
                $errout = 'Invalid option please try again........Try 0-4 or Q only'
            }
 
        }
    }
    until ($Menu -eq 'q')
}   
 
# Launch The Menu
Menu
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and clarify what problem you're having with your code.

Comment: if there is nothing wrong with your code, I would recommend asking on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for some advice/improvements.